# Plot multivariate-normal-distribution-like shape

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, gaussian, data-fitting

I have a set of 3D data points, which when plotted form a multivariate Gaussian kind of shape as shown in the picture.

[image]

However, **I need a nice and smooth contour plot which ideally could incorporate prior Gaussian shape information**.

I am not entirely sure where to start, as my points do not follow normal distribution they only have Gaussian shape, thus I cannot apply Gaussian Mixture Models to determine the distribution. Is that correct?

**Is there a way to do that?**

Ideally, I would like to get a plot which looks similar to this:

[image]

My code to plot the contour:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import cm
from scipy.interpolate import griddata


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax.set_title("NN-interpolated contour")

# Prep X-Y grid
xi = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), (len(z)))
yi = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), (len(z)))

# Interpolate using nearest neighbour
zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi[None, :], yi[:, None]), method='nearest')
xig, yig = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

# Plot
surf = ax.contourf(xig, yig, zi, cmap=cm.summer)
fig.colorbar(surf)
plt.show()
```

**EDIT:**

This is the plot with cubic interpolation:

[image]

Comment: From what I see from [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#multivariate-data-interpolation-griddata), you might want to use the `cubic` method with the call to `griddata`

Comment: What are `x`, `y` and `z`? The code looks correct. So as long as you don't provide a [mcve] of the issue, it's impossible to help.

Comment: @Adonis I edited post with the cubic plot

Comment: (If "nearest" does not work, why should "cubic" suddenly work?) That said, see my first comment.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest x, y, z are the points generated by the sensor. (x, y) is the position on the ground and z is the amplitude of the sound which occurred at that position. Therefore, you can see that there's a lot of noise, as sound is not always recorded due to the dead time of the sensor which generates the sound.

Comment: The result of the griddata interpolation will depend on the data. So it may well be that everything here works as expected. In that case, where should the gaussian shape originate from? How does your data relate to that "gaussian shape"?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest [Here](https://ufile.io/qj95l) you can find the 3D point set used in the plots.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest The sound generated follows Gaussian shape, hence if I was to remove the noise (all those (0,0,0) points) it does have bell-shape

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Hmm, maybe if I start working on cleaning the noise the NN interpolation method should work, I will go and try that

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Just pointing to the "cubic" one because from my understanding it smoothes out the curve. That said, indeed you're right it depends on the data

Comment: By the way, the data you posted are in a binary format, could you rather post them in a human readable format (csv for instance with 3 columns, x,y,z)?

Comment: ...and why is it again that you cannot fit a Gaussian to the data? You wrote * The sound generated follows Gaussian shape...*. So fit it and you'll get a *super nice* plot

Comment: @Adonis just try `numpy.load()`

Comment: ...may I ask why you measure so many zeros even in the centre where you should have large amplitude? That is not noise, but a problem with the sensor? In other words, for my taste there are by for to many exact zeros; and even removing those, you have strange outliers. Do you actually trust that measurement ( from a physicist point of view )?

Comment: ...removing the zeros and using `tricontourf` makes it slightly better, but not as nice as you desire.

Comment: @mikuszefski 1) My wording is not entirely correct, the amplitude of the sound generated by the sensor varies as parabolic/gaussian function, however, this data is collected by rotating around area and sweeping sensor from top to bottom, hence, once the sensor goes from top to bottom - one mean of "gaussian" function occurs and when you go from bottom to top - other mean occurs. Ideally, these peeks should overlap at the centre, but due to the velocity at which the sensor moves and some internal stabilisation feature of the sensor, we see this flat surface formed of multiple gaussian peeks.

Comment: @mikuszefski So I was thinking about that as well and figured that I could estimate my Gaussian parameters with GMM. However, I do not have the distribution as points do not follow normal distribution, hence that is what I did. I assumed that Z component of a point represents the probability of that point occurring in the distribution and normalized the total probability so that if you add Z components of all points you get 1. This helped me to get rid of 0s, as their probability in the distribution was 0, use GMM to estimate multivariate normal parameters and smoothen the outliner points.

Comment: @mikuszefski However, currently we are trying to figure out how exactly such procedure could be written down? Is that some well-known method? I got suggestions to look at the Gaussian Mixture Regression, would yo have any ideas?

Comment: hmmm...still not sure what you are doing...are you moving in `x`-`y`? Is that position? Is `z` intensity or amplitude at that position? I am wondering as you get very different `z` for similar `x`-`y`.

Comment: @mikuszefski Yes, the detector is pointing to the normal of the surface and collecting the signal intensity (sorry, I assume sound as the signal, so sound amplitude) at the x-y position. Btw,  x and y why are in meters

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167647/discussion-between-mikuszefski-and-laurynas-tamulevicius).